# Will all Drupal 7 Ubercart 3 orders be deleted if I disable & uninstall all Ubercart related modules?

Tags: 7, commerce, ubercart, migrations

I'm working on migrating a Ubercart site to Commerce and wanted to know if all Ubercart orders and tables will be deleted if I disable & uninstall all related modules. Since I don't need the old data, I don't mind it having it completely deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uninstall them, then yes.

EDIT:

No, they will not. Good call, duckx (I shouldn't have assumed that the D7 version implemented `hook_uninstall_schema()`).

Comment: actually they do not.. i just did an uninstall and see my database alot of the uc_ table are still there: ---->

uc_order_statuses
uc_orders
uc_packaged_products
uc_packages
uc_payment_check
uc_payment_cod
uc_payment_cybersource_hop_post
uc_payment_other
uc_payment_paypal_ipn
uc_payment_receipts
....

Comment: Good call @duckx -- I can only assume their reasoning for this is in case you want the data preserved...? #wtf

Comment: seems like i have to delete all this stuff myself. I hope it doesnt break anything even though all the modules are uninstalled. --- http://prntscr.com/19ej2b

Comment: correction ubercart did delete the tables. I must have somehow missed typing  drush pm-uninstall in my bash script